# How to get onclick event on graph3D (visjs) with bokeh?

Tags: typescript, bokeh, vis.js

On a bokeh server project, I would like to play a python callback on a click on a graph3D (visjs).
I've managed to extend bokeh to draw a scatter3D plot (thanks to [this example](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/wrapping.html#userguide-extensions-examples-wrapping)).
Next step is to get the click event and display something on js console, but I can't find out how to do it inside bokeh extension typescript code.

[visjs graph3d official documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-graph3d/docs/graph3d/index.html#Events) and [an example with js code](https://visjs.github.io/vis-graph3d/examples/graph3d/07_dot_cloud_colors.html) suggest to place  `graph.on('click', console.log("blabla"))`, but it gives me an error `Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Graph3d'`.
I also tried a `onclick: <function>` on Options as seen somewhere on stackoverflow, without success.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.core.properties import Instance, String
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LayoutDOM
from bokeh.util.compiler import TypeScript

TS_CODE = """
// This custom model wraps one part of the third-party vis.js library:
//
//     http://visjs.org/index.html
//
// Making it easy to hook up python data analytics tools (NumPy, SciPy,
// Pandas, etc.) to web presentations using the Bokeh server.

import {LayoutDOM, LayoutDOMView} from "models/layouts/layout_dom"
import {ColumnDataSource} from "models/sources/column_data_source"
import {LayoutItem} from "core/layout"
import * as p from "core/properties"

declare namespace vis {
  class Graph3d {
    constructor(el: HTMLElement, data: object, OPTIONS: object)
    setData(data: vis.DataSet): void
  }

  class DataSet {
    add(data: unknown): void
  }
}

// This defines some default options for the Graph3d feature of vis.js
// See: http://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html for more details.
const OPTIONS = {
  width: '600px',
  height: '600px',
  style: 'dot-color',
  showPerspective: true,
  showGrid: true,
  //onclick:  (point: any) => { console.log(point) }, // <- GIVES NOTHING
  //onclick: () => {console.log("bip")},              // <- DON'T WORK
  keepAspectRatio: true,
  verticalRatio: 1.0,
  cameraPosition: {
    horizontal: -0.35,
    vertical: 0.22,
    distance: 1.8,
  },

}
// To create custom model extensions that will render on to the HTML canvas
// or into the DOM, we must create a View subclass for the model.
//
// In this case we will subclass from the existing BokehJS ``LayoutDOMView``
export class Scatter3dView extends LayoutDOMView {
  model: Scatter3d

  private _graph: vis.Graph3d

  initialize(): void {
    super.initialize()

    const url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js"
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.onload = () => this._init()
    script.async = false
    script.src = url
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  private _init(): void {
    // Create a new Graph3s using the vis.js API. This assumes the vis.js has
    // already been loaded (e.g. in a custom app template). In the future Bokeh
    // models will be able to specify and load external scripts automatically.
    //
    // BokehJS Views create <div> elements by default, accessible as this.el.
    // Many Bokeh views ignore this default <div>, and instead do things like
    // draw to the HTML canvas. In this case though, we use the <div> to attach
    // a Graph3d to the DOM.
    this._graph = new vis.Graph3d(this.el, this.get_data(), OPTIONS)

    // Set a listener so that when the Bokeh data source has a change
    // event, we can process the new data
    this.connect(this.model.data_source.change, () => {
      this._graph.setData(this.get_data())
    })

    //this._graph.on('click', console.log("bob"))  // <-- gives error : Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Graph3d'

  }

  // This is the callback executed when the Bokeh data has an change. Its basic
  // function is to adapt the Bokeh data source to the vis.js DataSet format.
  get_data(): vis.DataSet {
    const data = new vis.DataSet()
    const source = this.model.data_source
    for (let i = 0; i < source.get_length()!; i++) {
      data.add({
        x: source.data[this.model.x][i],
        y: source.data[this.model.y][i],
        z: source.data[this.model.z][i],
        style:  source.data[this.model.color][i],
      })
    }
    return data
  }

  get child_models(): LayoutDOM[] {
    return []
  }

  _update_layout(): void {
    this.layout = new LayoutItem()
    this.layout.set_sizing(this.box_sizing())
  }
}

// We must also create a corresponding JavaScript BokehJS model subclass to
// correspond to the python Bokeh model subclass. In this case, since we want
// an element that can position itself in the DOM according to a Bokeh layout,
// we subclass from ``LayoutDOM``
export namespace Scatter3d {
  export type Attrs = p.AttrsOf<Props>

  export type Props = LayoutDOM.Props & {
    x: p.Property<string>
    y: p.Property<string>
    z: p.Property<string>
    color: p.Property<string>
    data_source: p.Property<ColumnDataSource>
  }
}

export interface Scatter3d extends Scatter3d.Attrs {}

export class Scatter3d extends LayoutDOM {
  properties: Scatter3d.Props
  __view_type__: Scatter3dView

  constructor(attrs?: Partial<Scatter3d.Attrs>) {
    super(attrs)
  }

  // The ``__name__`` class attribute should generally match exactly the name
  // of the corresponding Python class. Note that if using TypeScript, this
  // will be automatically filled in during compilation, so except in some
  // special cases, this shouldn't be generally included manually, to avoid
  // typos, which would prohibit serialization/deserialization of this model.
  static __name__ = "Scatter3d"

  static init_Scatter3d() {
    // This is usually boilerplate. In some cases there may not be a view.
    this.prototype.default_view = Scatter3dView

    // The @define block adds corresponding "properties" to the JS model. These
    // should basically line up 1-1 with the Python model class. Most property
    // types have counterparts, e.g. ``bokeh.core.properties.String`` will be
    // ``p.String`` in the JS implementatin. Where the JS type system is not yet
    // as rich, you can use ``p.Any`` as a "wildcard" property type.
    this.define<Scatter3d.Props>({
      x:            [ p.String   ],
      y:            [ p.String   ],
      z:            [ p.String   ],
      color:        [ p.String   ],
      data_source:  [ p.Instance ],
    })
  }
}
"""

# This custom extension model will have a DOM view that should layout-able in
# Bokeh layouts, so use ``LayoutDOM`` as the base class. If you wanted to create
# a custom tool, you could inherit from ``Tool``, or from ``Glyph`` if you
# wanted to create a custom glyph, etc.
class Scatter3d(LayoutDOM):
    # The special class attribute ``__implementation__`` should contain a string
    # of JavaScript code that implements the browser side of the extension model.
    __implementation__ = TypeScript(TS_CODE)

    # Below are all the "properties" for this model. Bokeh properties are
    # class attributes that define the fields (and their types) that can be
    # communicated automatically between Python and the browser. Properties
    # also support type validation. More information about properties in
    # can be found here:
    #
    #    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh-core-properties

    # This is a Bokeh ColumnDataSource that can be updated in the Bokeh
    # server by Python code
    data_source = Instance(ColumnDataSource)

    # The vis.js library that we are wrapping expects data for x, y, and z.
    # The data will actually be stored in the ColumnDataSource, but these
    # properties let us specify the *name* of the column that should be
    # used for each field.
    x = String
    y = String
    z = String
    color = String

X_data = np.random.normal(0, 10, 100)
Y_data = np.random.normal(0, 10, 100)
Z_data = np.random.normal(0, 10, 100)
color = np.asarray([0 for x in range(50)] + [1 for x in range(50)])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X_data, y=Y_data, z=Z_data, color=color))

myPlot = Scatter3d(x="x", y="y", z="z", color="color", data_source=source, width=600, height=600)

show(myPlot)
```

There will be next steps, like linking the js event to python callback, but this is another subject -I take all suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After further investigations, I found 2 things which are wrong on my code :

1. The call of `vis.js` lib is done for an old version
   `const url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js"`
   The last version is available via this url `const url = "https://unpkg.com/vis-graph3d@latest/dist/vis-graph3d.min.js"`
2. The error `Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Graph3d'` is an error raised by Typescript compiler.
   The `vis.js` documentation is very clear, `graph3d` as a `on` [property to handle events](https://visjs.github.io/vis-graph3d/docs/graph3d/index.html#Events)
   The compiler is somehow wrong. It can be overstep with addition of `// @ts-ignore` on the line before

Finally, a working code is the following

```
from bokeh.core.properties import Instance, String
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LayoutDOM
from bokeh.util.compiler import TypeScript

TS_CODE = """
// This custom model wraps one part of the third-party vis.js library:
//
//     http://visjs.org/index.html
//
// Making it easy to hook up python data analytics tools (NumPy, SciPy,
// Pandas, etc.) to web presentations using the Bokeh server.

import {LayoutDOM, LayoutDOMView} from "models/layouts/layout_dom"
import {ColumnDataSource} from "models/sources/column_data_source"
import {LayoutItem} from "core/layout"
import * as p from "core/properties"

declare namespace vis {
  class Graph3d {
    constructor(el: HTMLElement, data: object, OPTIONS: object)
    setData(data: vis.DataSet): void
  }

  class DataSet {
    add(data: unknown): void
  }
}

// This defines some default options for the Graph3d feature of vis.js
// See: http://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html for more details.
const OPTIONS = {
  width: '600px',
  height: '600px',
  style: 'dot-color',
  showPerspective: true,
  showGrid: false,
  keepAspectRatio: true,
  verticalRatio: 1.0,
  showLegend: false,
  cameraPosition: {
    horizontal: -0.35,
    vertical: 0.22,
    distance: 1.8,
  },
  tooltip:  (point: any) => {
          // parameter point contains properties x, y, z, and data
          // data is the original object passed to the point constructor
          return 'x: ' + point.x + ' y: ' + point.y + ' z: ' + point.z 
        },
}
// To create custom model extensions that will render on to the HTML canvas
// or into the DOM, we must create a View subclass for the model.
//
// In this case we will subclass from the existing BokehJS ``LayoutDOMView``
export class Scatter3DView extends LayoutDOMView {
  model: Scatter3D

  private _graph: vis.Graph3d

  initialize(): void {
    super.initialize()

    //const url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js"
    //const url = "visjs.min.js"
    const url = "https://unpkg.com/vis-graph3d@latest/dist/vis-graph3d.min.js"
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.onload = () => this._init()
    script.async = false
    script.src = url
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  private _init(): void {
    // Create a new Graph3s using the vis.js API. This assumes the vis.js has
    // already been loaded (e.g. in a custom app template). In the future Bokeh
    // models will be able to specify and load external scripts automatically.
    //
    // BokehJS Views create <div> elements by default, accessible as this.el.
    // Many Bokeh views ignore this default <div>, and instead do things like
    // draw to the HTML canvas. In this case though, we use the <div> to attach
    // a Graph3d to the DOM.
    this._graph = new vis.Graph3d(this.el, this.get_data(), OPTIONS)

    // Set a listener so that when the Bokeh data source has a change
    // event, we can process the new data
    this.connect(this.model.data_source.change, () => {
      this._graph.setData(this.get_data())
    })
    
    // @ts-ignore
    this._graph.on('click', this.on_click)
  }

  on_click(point: any): void {
      console.log(point)
  }

  // This is the callback executed when the Bokeh data has an change. Its basic
  // function is to adapt the Bokeh data source to the vis.js DataSet format.
  get_data(): vis.DataSet {
    const data = new vis.DataSet()
    const source = this.model.data_source
    for (let i = 0; i < source.get_length()!; i++) {
      data.add({
        x: source.data[this.model.x][i],
        y: source.data[this.model.y][i],
        z: source.data[this.model.z][i],
        style:  {"fill": String(source.data[this.model.color][i]), "stroke": "#FFF"},
        //style:  {"fill": "red", "stroke": "#999"},
        //style: 1,
      })
      //console.log(data)
    }
    return data
  }

  get child_models(): LayoutDOM[] {
    return []
  }

  _update_layout(): void {
    this.layout = new LayoutItem()
    this.layout.set_sizing(this.box_sizing())
  }
}

// We must also create a corresponding JavaScript BokehJS model subclass to
// correspond to the python Bokeh model subclass. In this case, since we want
// an element that can position itself in the DOM according to a Bokeh layout,
// we subclass from ``LayoutDOM``
export namespace Scatter3D {
  export type Attrs = p.AttrsOf<Props>

  export type Props = LayoutDOM.Props & {
    x: p.Property<string>
    y: p.Property<string>
    z: p.Property<string>
    color: p.Property<string>
    data_source: p.Property<ColumnDataSource>
  }
}

export interface Scatter3D extends Scatter3D.Attrs {}

export class Scatter3D extends LayoutDOM {
  properties: Scatter3D.Props
  __view_type__: Scatter3DView

  constructor(attrs?: Partial<Scatter3D.Attrs>) {
    super(attrs)
  }

  // The ``__name__`` class attribute should generally match exactly the name
  // of the corresponding Python class. Note that if using TypeScript, this
  // will be automatically filled in during compilation, so except in some
  // special cases, this shouldn't be generally included manually, to avoid
  // typos, which would prohibit serialization/deserialization of this model.
  static __name__ = "Scatter3D"

  static init_Scatter3D() {
    // This is usually boilerplate. In some cases there may not be a view.
    this.prototype.default_view = Scatter3DView

    // The @define block adds corresponding "properties" to the JS model. These
    // should basically line up 1-1 with the Python model class. Most property
    // types have counterparts, e.g. ``bokeh.core.properties.String`` will be
    // ``p.String`` in the JS implementatin. Where the JS type system is not yet
    // as rich, you can use ``p.Any`` as a "wildcard" property type.
    this.define<Scatter3D.Props>({
      x:            [ p.String   ],
      y:            [ p.String   ],
      z:            [ p.String   ],
      color:        [ p.String   ],
      data_source:  [ p.Instance ],
    })
  }
}
"""


# This custom extension model will have a DOM view that should layout-able in
# Bokeh layouts, so use ``LayoutDOM`` as the base class. If you wanted to create
# a custom tool, you could inherit from ``Tool``, or from ``Glyph`` if you
# wanted to create a custom glyph, etc.
class Scatter3D(LayoutDOM):
    # The special class attribute ``__implementation__`` should contain a string
    # of JavaScript code that implements the browser side of the extension model.
    __implementation__ = TypeScript(TS_CODE)

    # Below are all the "properties" for this model. Bokeh properties are
    # class attributes that define the fields (and their types) that can be
    # communicated automatically between Python and the browser. Properties
    # also support type validation. More information about properties in
    # can be found here:
    #
    #    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh-core-properties

    # This is a Bokeh ColumnDataSource that can be updated in the Bokeh
    # server by Python code
    data_source = Instance(ColumnDataSource)

    # The vis.js library that we are wrapping expects data for x, y, and z.
    # The data will actually be stored in the ColumnDataSource, but these
    # properties let us specify the *name* of the column that should be
    # used for each field.
    x = String
    y = String
    z = String
    color = String
```

I'm now looking for a way to pass to bokeh server this click information. Have you an idea how to do it ?